# A section for "must read"

Tags: feature-request, new-users

Every once in awhile, some one gives such a kick-ass answer full of so much information that I just bookmark it. I have a small collection of answers that I thought were really insightful, that I wish I could nominate for "answer of the month" so that new people that come to the site would be able to click on "all-time awesome answers" and read some of the content that was exceptional - **even if it was done a year ago**. Like a hall of fame of best answers. We could automatically pick these based on "most votes this month" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "question" [Most Viewed Questions on GIS.SE](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/494/most-viewed-questions-on-gis-se) demonstrates one mechanism that might accomplish this: you can query the SE database itself to find what you consider to be "best" answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the sort of thing that [the Blog](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/) is ideal for.