# Most Viewed Questions on GIS.SE

Tags: discussion, statistics

I had a brief look at the stats for GIS.SE via http://data.stackexchange.com where you can create your own queries. I tried sorting by number of page views using the following query, which is also [saved here](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/q/102343/).

```
SELECT TOP 100
    p.Id as [Post Link],
    p.AnswerCount as [Answers],
    Score as [Votes],
    ViewCount  as [Views]
FROM Posts p
ORDER BY p.ViewCount DESC
```

The top 10 by page views are listed below. I think it's a nice mix of cartography, theory, data conversion, and programming.

- Examples of Beautiful Maps
- How can I convert KML to ESRI's shapefile format?
- How do I convert MapInfo TAB and/or MIF to SHP?
- Concave Hull: Definition, Algorithms and Practical Solutions
- How to a convert LiDAR XYZ files to DEM / DSM?
- Export table from ArcGis to Excel file
- What's the difference between a projection and a datum?
- Why is the 'straight line' path across continent so curved?
- How do I explain what GIS is for the 11 year old kid?
- How do I access arcobjects from python?

Comment: +1 this is cool.  I wonder how [long the tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Tail) is, i.e. what percentage of all views goes to the top twenty percent viewed posts?

Comment: I think this would be an excelent BLOG article.  I inadvertently stumbled upon this one, and most casual users may never spend any time in META.

Answer (score 4):

It is also interesting to look at the most upvoted *answers*:

```
SELECT top 12
     p.score, p.id as [Post Link]
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 2

GROUP BY p.score, p.id
ORDER BY p.score DESC
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
Score Post link
53    What is the most annoying fact about the GIS market/industry?
50    Why is the 'straight line' path across continent so curved?
45    How can I convert between KML and ESRI's shapefile format?
36    What is the most annoying fact about the GIS market/industry?
34    Comparison of JavaScript mapping libraries?
32    Colour blind cartography
32    GIS Pros - What free programs should every GIS user have installed?
30    What are the FOSS equivalents to these ArcGIS products?
29    How much math does a GIS Analyst need to know?
29    GIS Pros - What free programs should every GIS user have installed?
28    What's the difference between a projection and a datum?
28    What is the most annoying fact about the GIS market/industry?
```